# update statement is not working ..could anyone check into this

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

```
Bank_products Table:-
------    -------   -----------  -------------
itemid    revid    product_type    status
------     -----   -----------     --------
A001        123      banking         BA
A011        234      banking         BAA
A011        456      Non-banking     BAA
E004        786      Non-banking     NBA
A012        023      banking         BA
A201        123      Non-banking     NBA
A301        312      Commercial      COM
C405        023    Non-Commercial    NCOM
D003        111    Non-Commercial    NCOM
AB011       0001     banking         BAA
AB011       01246    Non-banking     BAA
----------------------------------------

select itemid, revid, product_type,
case when product_type='banking' then 'BA'
when product_type='Non-banking' then 'NBA'
when product_type='banking' or product_type='Non-banking' then 'BAA'
when product_type='Commerical' then 'COM'
when product_type='Non-commercial' then 'NCOM' end
from bank_products
where product_type in ('banking','Non-banking' ,'Commerical' ,'Non-commercial')
group by itemid, revid.
```

Here for one itemid we can have multiple revid's.
Now i need to update the update the status column in bank_products table based on select query...

My update query is not working properly. please help..

```
UPDATE bank_products
SET STATUS=
(case when product_type='banking' then 'BA'
when product_type='Non-banking' then 'NBA'
when product_type='banking' or product_type='Non-banking' then 'BAA'
when product_type='Commerical' then 'COM'
when product_type='Non-commercial' then 'NCOM' end)
WHERE product_type in ('banking','Non-banking' ,'Commerical' ,'Non-commercial')
group by itemid, revid.
```

Comment: Why GROUP BY when no aggregate functions are involved?

Comment: Remove `group by` in your query, it should work

Comment: You are checking for "banking" (and "Non-banking") twice

Comment: "not working properly" - please specify: what do you want to happen, what does happen? Any sample data maybe?

Comment: @badri . . . I would suggest that you ask *another* question.  Provide not only sample data, but also desired results and explain the logic.  Also, fix the typos in your strings -- perhaps that is the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Once check this and see if this works...

```
UPDATE bank_products
SET STATUS=
(case when product_type='banking' then 'BA'
when product_type='Non-banking' then 'NBA'
when product_type='Commercial' then 'COM'
when product_type='Non-commercial' then 'NCOM' end)
WHERE product_type in ('banking','Non-banking' ,'Commercial' ,'Non-commercial')
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi at first place your select query won't work,  because you putting case for same row you are checking two different column value that is not going to happen when it come to row `A011 234` the value of that product at any given point will be `banking` so it will update as `BA` not as BAA it doesn't validate the next row value in order to have that you should have the next row value as separate column then your select will work, Try using CTE you should be able to get this work as you expected.